# Trigger GitHub Action when push from specific branch

Tags: github-actions

We have a branch model with feature branches, develop, staging (for testing) and master for release.
Now we have an action for the Release notes, which creates a Pull Request with the actual release notes when pushing to staging or master.

But the action should only run when we push a Pull Request from develop into staging and from staging into master, but not when pushing from the release notes branch into staging or master. Is this possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since your release notes are likely being generated in a specific path (inferred from the fact that you're making a new PR containing the new release notes), you can ignore that path in your "on push"-triggered action. This means that the action will not be triggered on pushes to `master` or `staging` unless at least 1 changed file is outside the ignored path:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
    - 'release_notes/**'
    branches:
      - master
      - staging
# ...
```

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths