# On GitHub Actions, how do I run a job if a specific file in a specific branch has been pushed to?

Tags: github, github-actions

On GitHub Actions, how do I run a job if a specific file in a specific branch has been pushed to?

I've used the following workflow, but I don't know how to specify a specific branch for that file (such as the `main` branch):

```
on:
  push:
    paths: [ index.js ]
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: [`on.push.branches`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger GitHub Action when push from specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467902/trigger-github-action-when-push-from-specific-branch)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Would having `paths: [ index.js ]` and `branches: [ main ]` under `push:` make the action run if the path is `index.js` ***AND*** the branch is `main` or would it run if the path is `index.js` ***OR*** the branch is `main`? I thought it was ***OR***, but I may be wrong about this.

Comment: The docs aren't super clear about this, but there's a sentence on the [`paths` filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths): "Path filters are not evaluated for pushes to tags." I interpret that as that they *are* evaluated in all other cases, and behave like logical AND. I checked a workflow I have somewhere that uses both `branches` and `paths` (and also `types`, for good measure), and it's only run when all conditions are met.

Answer (score 3):

I have this running with.

Then it's only runs on `push` with changes in `.github/workflows/BranchAndPath.yml` and `README.md`

```
name: Branch & Path

on:  
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"
    paths: 
      - '.github/workflows/BranchAndPath.yml'
      - 'README.md'
```